I have problem with library. Can you you help me?
Git bash gave me this errorstrong text
5./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies
> Task:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifacts Debug FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



What went wrong:



Execution failed for task 'tapp:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'. Could not resolve all files for configuration':app:debugCompileClasspath'.



> Could not find com. nabinbhandari.android:permissions: 3.8.



Required by:



project app



Could not find ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5.



Required by:



project:app



> Could not find com.tapadoo.android:alerter: 2.0.4.



Required by:



project:app



> Could not find com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.5.1.



Required by:



project:app



> Could not find com.whiteelephant: monthandyearpicker:1.3.0.



Required by:



project:app


All the dependencies that you have listed have not been maintained in several years and have probably been hosted on JCenter.
Due to the fact JCenter is shutting down, it means the owners of these libraries need to migrate them to mavenCentral.
Your options are to:

Clone the repositories and work on them so they are up to date with the current API levels
Find more recent alternative libraries that help you do what you are after


All these dependencies part of jcenter which are not supported anymore. find alternate dependencies or download these and use as a module.
